# Multiple image slider doesn't work ? only two image are sliding but i need more then 2 image slide?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have a multiple div slider that are sliding step by step, In my slider i have combined 4 div slider, in every div i have 2 image that are sliding fine but..
1. i need more then 2 image sliding in every slider.
2. In a sliding loop every single slide should slide different animation like slideUp, SlideDown, slideLeft, SlideRight.
3. Another problem is when the page is refresh or loading the slider working fine but when i have scroll or visit another tab and again i visit on my slide without refresh or loading page slider are not working but when refresh page it work well.

HTML, CSS, Jquery

MySQL

```
<!-- Slider section -->
   <section class="slider-sec">
        <div class="slider-sec-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-sec-left">
                <div id="myslide">
                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft" data-display="0">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s1.jpg"  border="0" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft" data-display="1">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s2.jpg" class="slide" border="0" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="2">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s3.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="3">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s3.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider-sec-right">
                <div class="sli-right-top">
                    <div class="sl-top-sli">
                        <div id="myslide">
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="4">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/sli-right.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="5">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/institute.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="6">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/institute.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="7">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/institute.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sli-right-bottom">
                    <div class="sli-right-bottom-left">
                        <div id="myslide">
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="8">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft" data-display="9">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s5.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft" data-display="10">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft" data-display="11">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sli-right-bottom-right">
                        <div id="myslide">
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft" data-display="12">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="13">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="14">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s5.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight" data-display="15">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s5.jpg" class="slide"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
   </section>
   <!-- Slider section -->
```

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var InfiniteRotator = {
            init: function () {
                //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
                var initialFadeIn = 2000;
                //interval between items (in milliseconds)
                var itemInterval = 1000;
                //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
                var fadeTime = 1000;
                //count number of items
                var rotationLimit = $('div#myslide').length + 1;
                //set current item
                var currentItem = 0;
                //loop through the items
                var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
                    $('div#myslide').eq(currentItem).find('.rotating-home').fadeToggle(fadeTime);
                    currentItem++;
                    if(currentItem == rotationLimit) currentItem = 0;
                }, itemInterval);
            }
        };
        InfiniteRotator.init();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: ids should be unique, use a class instead

Comment: Sorry, Pete, It doesn't work.. for me

Comment: @Pete is right: please try changing `<div id="myslide">` to `<div class="myslide">` and in js: `$('div#myslide')` to `$('div.myslide')`

Comment: Please Help me to slide more then 2 image in every slider ...when i run it just slide between 2 image, third, fourth image are not sliding..

Comment: I have already change id to class in html and jquery as you say, nothing happened ...